# Context provider not updating default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm having some trouble modifying the default value given by a context. Below is a heavily simplified code, which still leads to the issue: As seen in the provider, I want greetWorld to become true, thus exhibiting "Hello world" instead of "..."

index.tsx:

```
import useSample, { SampleProvider } from './useSample'

const Example = () => {
  const { greetWorld } = useSample()
  
  return (
    <SampleProvider>
      {greetWorld ? 'Hello world' : '...'}
    </SampleProvider>
  )
}
```

useSample.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

type SampleContextType = {
  greetWorld: boolean
}

const SampleContext = React.createContext<SampleContextType>({
  greetWorld: false
})

export const SampleProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [greetWorld, setGreetWorld] = React.useState(true)
  const value = React.useMemo(() => ({
    greetWorld,
    setGreetWorld
  }), [greetWorld, setGreetWorld])

  return <SampleContext.Provider value={value}>{ children }</SampleContext.Provider>
}

const useSample = () => {
  const { greetWorld } = React.useContext(SampleContext)
  return { greetWorld }
}

export default useSample
```

From my current understanding, `greetWorld` in `index.tsx` would get its value based on `useSample`'s `greetWorld`, which in turn would be the `greetWorld` value given in `SampleProvider`, which is true. I've tried logging the `greetWorld` inside `SampleProvider`, and it shows `true`, so I'm assuming that `SampleProvider` is being reached properly, but I have no idea why things aren't being updated.

Regarding similar issues, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082932/contexts-provider-default-value-function-gets-invoked-not-the-function-inside) seemed rather similar, but in my simplified code there's no tag order to respect in the first place, so it can't be that, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411744/reactjs-context-not-updated-values-always-default) also seemed a little like my problem, but from what I can see, it seems like the consumer is the child already.

I get the feeling that the solution is rather obvious, as I'm unfamiliar with context hooks, but I wasn't able to find it. On a side note, since I'm also unfamiliar with memoization, I left it there, as it could be among the causes of the problem, but I also tried removing it and the problem persisted.

Comment: The call to `useSample` is not a child of the `<SampleProvider />`.

Comment: The reason you are rendering "..." is `useSample` is accessing the default value of your `SampleContext` which is `false`, and as @super mentioned, `useSample` is not a child of `SampleProvider`, so it doesn't have access to it's state value.

Comment: Also, it would be better if you put your `SampleProvider` on a more top level. If you're using Nextjs, wrap your component in the `_app` file with your Context Provider.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does that mean that if I move `SampleProvider` to wrap the component exported from `index.js`, the problem should go away? So something like... `export default Example` and in the file that uses it, 

`<SampleProvider><Example/></SampleProvider>`

Comment: @Rapha-Y that would be the ideal use of your Context Provider. Try that and let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: It did, thank you. Unfortunately, that led to another problem, but that's something I'll solve on my own or open another question for, therefore this should be enough for this thread.

Comment: @Rapha-Y As for this question, should I answer it so you can close this thread?

Comment: Sure, feel free to do so.